# add onclick event radio buttons django forms

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

So i have a form i use django forms to render out and i have radio buttons that i have added the `onclick` function to using the code below.

```
class Profile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "avatar",
            "staff_id",
            "matric_no",
            "library_id",
            "designation",
            "lib_user",
        ]
        widgets = {
            "designation": forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
                "id":"label_68",
                "class":"form-radio validate[required]",
                "required":"", 
                "name":"q68_typeA68",
                "onclick":"myFunction(0)",
            }),
        }
```

whenever the form is rendered in html, it look like this

```
<input type="radio" name="lib_user" value="" id="label_70_0" class="form-radio validate[required]" aria-describedby="label_70" name="q70_typeA70" onclick="myFunction1(0)">
<input type="radio" name="lib_user" value="Yes" id="label_70_1" class="form-radio validate[required]" aria-describedby="label_70" name="q70_typeA70" onclick="myFunction1(0)">
<input type="radio" name="lib_user" value="No" id="label_70_2" class="form-radio validate[required]" aria-describedby="label_70" name="q70_typeA70" onclick="myFunction1(0)">
```

what i want to achieve is this

```
<input type="radio" name="lib_user" value="" id="label_70_0" class="form-radio validate[required]" aria-describedby="label_70" name="q70_typeA70" onclick="myFunction1(0)">
<input type="radio" name="lib_user" value="Yes" id="label_70_1" class="form-radio validate[required]" aria-describedby="label_70" name="q70_typeA70" onclick="myFunction1(1)">
<input type="radio" name="lib_user" value="No" id="label_70_2" class="form-radio validate[required]" aria-describedby="label_70" name="q70_typeA70" onclick="myFunction1(2)">
```

So how do i go about it is what i need help with.

Comment: Isn't there an easier way? What about calling `myFunction()` without arg and then fetch the index `var index = idOfElement.split("_")[idOfElement.split("_") - 1]` ?

Comment: Can you please explain better as i am not a javascript developer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, what it does is overwrite the **init** method of the Profile form and the for loop goes through the widgets and adds the onclick event:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for i, (value, widget) in enumerate(self.fields["lib_user"].widget.choices):
        widget.attrs["onclick"] = f"myFunction1({i})"
```